# How to invoke a lambda custom authorizer on every request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-stack

I have a lambda function with an authorizer sitting within an API gateway.

I notice that when I call the lambda function, on the first request the authorizer is invoked as expected, authorization passes, IAM role is assumed and grants access to the lambda function.

However, on subsequent requests, the authorizer is not invoked.

I assume this is due to authorization caching.

However, in the AWS console, in `API gateway > Authorizers` the authorizer has the following configuration:

```
Authorizer ID: iiii2l

Lambda Function
 foo-authorizerV1-dev-authorizer (eu-west-1)

Lambda Invoke Role
 arn:aws:iam::0000000:role/foo-authorizerV1-dev-AuthorizerRole-AAAAAAA

Lambda Event Payload
 Request

Identity Sources
 deviceID (header)

Authorization Caching
 Authorization not cached
```

I would have thought `Authorization Caching` being set to `Authorization not cached`  would mean that the authorizer would be invoked on every request.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If caching is not enabled then API Gateway will call the authorizer on each request.

If you've made a change to the API Gateway in the console but haven't yet deployed the API it might seem like you have one thing configuration but behavior for another. I would check that the current configuration is deployed and retest.